# How can I encode html file after read file with ZipFile?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, unicode, character-encoding

I am reading a zip file from a URL. Inside the zip file, there is an HTML file. After I read the file everything works fine. But when I print the text I am facing a Unicode problem. Python version: 3.8

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
content = requests.get("www.url.com")
zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(content.content))
file_name = zf.namelist()[0]
file = zf.open(file_name)

soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(),'html.parser',from_encoding='utf-8',exclude_encodings='utf-8')
for product in soup.find_all('tr'):
    product = product.find_all('td')
    if len(product) < 2: continue
    print(product[1].text)
```

I already try to open file and print text with `.decode('utf-8')` I got following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I add `from_encoding` and `exclude_encodings` in BeautifulSoup but nothing change and I didn't get an error.

Expected prints:

```
ÇEŞİTLİ MADDELER TOPLAMI
Tarçın
Fidanı
```

What I am getting:

```
ÇEÞÝTLÝ MADDELER TOPLAMI
Tarçýn
Fidaný
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at the file and the encoding is not `utf-8`, but `iso-8859-9`.
Change the encoding and everything will be fine:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(),'html.parser',from_encoding='iso-8859-9')
```

This will output: `ÇEŞİTLİ MADDELER TOPLAMI`

Comment: there is no encoing argument in zipfile.open I am getting the following error.
`open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`

Comment: Thank you bro but the result same

Comment: i think the encoding you are looking for is `iso-8859-9`. I had not noticed the slight difference ...

Comment: `file.read().decode('iso-8859-9')` work finally thank you so much you can update your answer also I delete `from_encoding` attribute.